# How to convert this sql request to Lambda expression or LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, lambda

How can I convert the following query to a lambda expression or to LINQ?

```
SELECT * FROM PrelevementClient as pc
LEFT JOIN ContratIBAN AS ci ON ci.IDCMPT = pc.IDCMPT
LEFT JOIN Contrat AS ctr ON ctr.NOCONTRAT = ci.NOCONTRAT
WHERE pc.IDPRELEVEMENT = '111'
AND DTPROCHAINPREL >= getdate()
```

The difficulty is that there are two left joins.

Comment: It's hard to answer w/o having the entity model (the 3 entities involved and their relationships).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After each 'join' there is a 'from'.

Grouping all 'from' at the end of the request generates an issue.

```
 DateTime date = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
        var prelevements = from pc in set.Where(s => s.DTPROCHAINPREL >= DateTime.Today && s.NOSOC == nosoc && s.DTPROCHAINPREL < date)
                           join ci in context.Set<ContratIBAN>().Where( g => g.PRELEVEMENTBCA == true) on pc.IDCMPT equals ci.IDCMPT into cileft
                          from ci in cileft.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           join co in context.Set<Contrat>() on ci.NOCONTRAT equals co.NOCONTRAT into coleft     
                          from co in coleft.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps:

```
var query = from pc in Context.PrelevementClient
            join ci in Context.ContratIBAN on pc.IDCMPT equals ci.IDCMPT into ciLeft
            from ci in ciLeft.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join co in Context.Contrat on ci.nocontrat equals co.nocontrat into coLeft
            from co in coLeft.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where pc.idprelevement == "111" && pc.dtprochainprel >= DateTime.Today
            select new  
            {
              //bind what you want
              // and dont forget to manage if co||ci.property is null...
            }
```

Comment: I think we can improve the answer by providing a complete query.

Comment: Third line produces "CS0103 - The name 'ci' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Still the same. You missed the point. After `into ciLeft`, `ci` is out of context.